# mysql dump query hangs

Tags: mysql

I have run  mysql -u root -p gf < ~/gf_backup.sql   to restore my db. However when I see the process list I see that one query has has been idle for a long time. I do not know the reason why.

```
mysql> show processlist;
    +-----+------+-----------+-------------+---------+-------+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    | Id  | User | Host      | db          | Command | Time  | State     | Info                                                                                                 |
    +-----+------+-----------+-------------+---------+-------+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    | 662 | root | localhost | gf | Query   | 18925 | query end | INSERT INTO `gf_1` VALUES (1767654,'90026','Lddd',3343,34349),(1 |
    | 672 | root | localhost | gf | Query   |     0 | NULL      | show processlist                                                                                     |
    +-----+------+-----------+-------------+---------+-------+-----------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Can you post your database schema with the table descriptions and any relationships/constraints?   Without knowing what your tables are, it's nearly impossible to nail down what could be going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your dump is very large and contains much normalized data (records split into a bunch of tables, with a bunch of foreign key constraints, indexes and so on).

If so, you may try to remove all constraints and index definitions from the SQL file, then import the data and re-create the former removed directives. This is a well-known trick to speed up imports, because `INSERT` commands without validation of any constraints are a lot faster, and creation of an index and so on afterwards can be done in a single transaction.

See also: http://support.tigertech.net/mysql-large-inserts

Of course, you should kill the query first. And remove all fragments it created already.

Comment: Could the query hang possibly because I do not have enough disk space?

Comment: In theory, yes... But can't you check for that?!

Answer (score 1):

Please check free space with df -h command (if under Linux/Unix) if you're out of space do not kill or restart MySQL until it catch up with changes when you free some space.

you may also want to check max_allowed_packet setting in my.cnf and set it to something like 256M, please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet